# Code Colouring for Website Display

Tags: jquery, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

Is there a JQuery/Javascript module for colouring code? I've got a website where I talk about the projects I'm currently involved in and that quite often involves outputting some of my code.

I would like some way of colouring the code as it does on this website and many other websites to give it higher readability.

Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reccomend **[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)** by Alex Gorbatchev.

SyntaxHighlighter is a fully functional self-contained code syntax highlighter developed in JavaScript.

But there is also:

- [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
- [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)
- [and a lot more ...](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/)